# JQuery append is not doing as intended

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, append

I have a problem with my JQuery script. I am making a 2d chat where people have their own figure like Habbo hotel, but the JQuery script that is suppose to move the figures is bugging.

I think it is easier to show the problem:
[Click here to see the problem](http://imezzo.dk/hej/)

I am using the following script to update the figures:

```
function UpdateRoom() {
    var data = 'roomId='+roomId;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",  
        url: "chatfunctions/updateroom.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){

            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                var temp = parseInt(data.field);
                $('#f' + temp).append('<div class="user" id="'+charId+'" />');
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

The #f+temp is the id of the field that the figure should be places at. The charId is the id of the figure.

And then I am calling the script every 500 miliseconds:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    UpdateRoom();
}, 500 );
```

Im not sure if this is enough code and example for you guys to help me. If not please tell me if I need to provide more for you to help me. My guess is that it is the .append(); function that is used wrong, but I'm no expert in JQuery.

Comment: As you see it is like that append is just duplicating the figures, it needs to replace it.

Comment: To replace it, use `html()` instead. And all though it's working, you probably should'nt name all your variables `data`.

Comment: What is charId here.. I don't see that in the code

Comment: You code does what it suppose to do. Append does not replace anything and would not be intended to do so. I don't see anywhere in your code where you remove/replace any elements. See http://api.jquery.com/append/ for more details.

Comment: @Sushanth-- -> charId is the id of the "user" right now its just a global variable with a random generated number

Comment: But if im not suppose to use append is there anything else that you can recommend?

Comment: Holy crap -> [**HTML()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Use $('#f' + temp).html('<div class="user" id="'+charId+'" />');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only continuing to append but not replacing anything.

Try to either use .html() or .empty().

```
$.each(data, function(i, data) {
    var temp = parseInt(data.field);
    $('#f' + temp).html('<div class="user" id="'+charId+'" />');
});
```

or

```
$.each(data, function(i, data) {
    var temp = parseInt(data.field);
    $('#f' + temp).empty(); // clear out all content
    $('#f' + temp).append('<div class="user" id="'+charId+'" />');
});
```

not knowing your code you might need to move the call to .empty() outside your each loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Now the site is not going crazy like before, not it just duplicates. I have updated the site så you can try refresh and see the changes :)

Comment: @JonasHansen - We don't really care how your site looks, if the answer is correct accept it as such.